# .htaccess not redirecting subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

Hello i'd created a htaccess file to pass every petition through a wrapper.php file.

Here's the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wrapper.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

My folder structure is this one:

```
* root
  * .htaccess file
  * my-folder
     * admin
         * recover.php
```

I tried everything in localhost (using xampp) and works perfectly. But the problem is when i upload my site contents to a hosting, don't work.

I'll explain if I access to http://example.com or http://example.com/admin/ my wrapper receive correctly the parameters and is able to handle it, but when I access to http://example.com/admin/recover/, for example, there's a file inside /admin/ called recover.php and the wrapper is not handling anything. I guess it is something with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. But my question is why in localhost everything pass first through wrapper.php but in my hosting it calls the file (recover.php in this case) first if this exists.

Edit:

I tried to change the wrapper so instead of include a recover.php file, when /admin/recover/ is called, to include recover-password.php

And now works fine, but keep not understanding why in localhost the wrapper is called first instead of the actual file.

I want to make it work without renaming all files inside /admin/

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your webhost allows .htaccess files? If you remove the .htaccess from your webhost does it behave the same way?

Comment: The .htaccess file works fine when I access to http://example.com or http://example.com/admin/. So yes I guess my webhost allows .htaccess files. @kojow7

Comment: Is this the only rewrite rule that you have set up? If you go to example.com/blahblahblah does it redirect you to wrapper.php?

Comment: Well I googled and the way to redirect to anyfile and handle it this way is putting only that rewrite condition in .htaccess. @kojow7

Comment: What about the second question I asked?

Comment: Didn't see that sorry. In my wrapper I handle that kind of "error" like a 404 error, so I just include error404.php when the /blahblahblah for example was not expected as page. @kojow7

Comment: I am wondering if your web host is making the .php extension optional. You can confirm this by deleting or renaming your .htaccess file and trying to connect to example.com/admin/recover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem is remote host enabling `MultiViews` option.

Place this line at top of your .htaccess to turn off `MultiViews`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: It was that, it worked, thank you! Just to understand, what was the problem?

Comment: `MultiViews` causes URIs to match their corresponding matching file names so URI as `/file` will make it `/file.php`. That happens before `mod_rewrite` module hence your condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will fail.